signOut(auth); redirects to / and not to intended route
signOut(auth); redirects to / and not to intended route
I want the redirection to be /adminmodule/login, but redirects to / instead. I it possible to modify the redirection of signout auth.
const handleLogout = async (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const auth = getAuth();
    try {
        console.log(userType);
        await signOut(auth);

        // Redirect based on userType
        if (userType === 'client') {
            router.push('/client');
        } else if (userType === 'admin' || userType === 'superadmin') {
            router.push('/adminmodule/login');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error logging out:", error);
    }
};

return (
    <aside>
        <div onClick={handleLogout} className={`h-12 flex items-center space-x-4 bg-[#FF2C2C]`}>
            {isHovered && (
                <p>Logout</p>
            )}
        </div>
    </aside>
);

